# Does firestore rules validate every time when listener added?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is the question previously i asked [Questions about firestore cache and reads charge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617814/questions-about-firestore-cache-and-reads-charge)

Basically it says if i add same listener like below twice, I only get charge as single listener for receiving data.

```
db.collection("testCollection").onSnapshot(function(doc) {}); 
db.collection("testCollection").onSnapshot(function(doc) {});
```

But if I using `get` in rules on that path

```
match /testCollection/{documentId} {
   allow list: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAllowToReadTestCollection;
}
```

Will the rules validate twice? Will I get charged for that `get` in rules twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in the linked answer - since the listeners get deduped on the client before reaching the server, there should also only be a single evaluation of the security rules.